# How to fix the user account control attribute to 512 in Ldap

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Using Java code I am trying to crate user in AD LDAP but I am not able to set the `userAccountControl` status to 512 though I am trying to pass the status as 512 through my code but the user is created with different `userAccountControl` status as 544.

And when the user is created I am not able to login with his id (DN) and password into LDAP.

I am using the code :

```
attributes.add(new LDAPAttribute("userAccountControl", "512"));
attributes.add(new LDAPAttribute("userPassword", "Password@1"));
```

Is there any other way I can set the `userAccountControl` to 512?

Answer (score 1):

A `userAccountControl` value of 544 is 512 + 32, which [means](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-useraccountcontrol#remarks) `NORMAL_ACCOUNT` + `PASSWD_NOTREQD`, probably because it doesn't have a password when you created it. You can't set it to 512 if it doesn't have a password.

Setting the password has to be done in a second step, after you create the account. AD is a bit weird in that the `userPassword` attribute even exists, when it only sometimes behaves as you imagine it should. You can read about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/f3adda9f-89e1-4340-a3f2-1f0a6249f1f8) if you want. But you would be better off just setting [`unicodePwd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/6e803168-f140-4d23-b2d3-c3a8ab5917d2) instead, which always works the same way, although it is a bit of a weird format.

There is a Java example of doing this [here](https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/91c2df9b5481b30e5ca213a7baa0ce7e0a04752c/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/ADConnection.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#lines-157):

```
public void updateUserPassword(String username, String password)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("updating password...\n");
        String quotedPassword = "\"" + password + "\"";
        char unicodePwd[] = quotedPassword.toCharArray();
        byte pwdArray[] = new byte[unicodePwd.length * 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < unicodePwd.length; i++)
        {
            pwdArray[i * 2 + 1] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] >>> 8);
            pwdArray[i * 2 + 0] = (byte) (unicodePwd[i] & 0xff);
        }
        System.out.print("encoded password: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < pwdArray.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(pwdArray[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        ModificationItem[] mods = new ModificationItem[1];
        mods[0] = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, new BasicAttribute("UnicodePwd", pwdArray));
        ldapContext.modifyAttributes("cn=" + username + BASE_NAME, mods);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("update password error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Note that you *must* be using LDAPS (LDAP over SSL, usually on port 636) to be able to set the password.

You can set the `userAccountControl` to 512 in the same request where you set the password.